# Session blocks itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a procedure which performs `MERGE`. `sp_who2` shows that session blocks itself. How is that possible? My sp looks like this

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp] as  
BEGIN  
    MERGE dbo.table as target  
    USING (  
        select field1, field2
        from dbo.view
    ) as source (field1, field2)  
    ON target.field1=source.field1 and target.field2=source.field2
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN  
    DELETE  
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT (field1, field2) VALUES (source.field1, source.field2);  
END
```

`dbo.table` is massive huge table. Has `IX_table(field1)` and `PK_table(field2,field1)`

`sp_who2` looks like this

[image]

Version -

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU16) (KB4508218) - 14.0.3223.3 (X64)
>   Jul 12 2019 17:43:08   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation 
>   Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 
>   (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: This is due to thread coordination (CXPACKET waits) the parallel query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting rid of the sub-query first.  If that doesn't work try adding the `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` below to remove parallelism from the query.

```
MERGE dbo.table as target  
USING dbo.view AS source
ON target.field1=source.field1 and target.field2=source.field2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN  
DELETE  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
INSERT (field1, field2) VALUES (source.field1, source.field2)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Comment: is it better to run with parallelism or without though?

Comment: Generally it's good, so if you can restructure the query somehow so it's not tripping over itself that would be ideal.  That's why I suggested eliminating the sub-query first.  My guess is that your view references the table so different threads are locking up the table.  You could also try replacing the view with the query contents of the view (without using a subquery in brackets just the table joins).  That might help the query engine devise a better plan.